# Continuous surjection from $ [0, 1] $ to $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

I need to find such path connected compact subset $X$ of $\Bbb R^2$ that the continuous surjection $[0, 1] \rightarrow X$ doesn't exists.

I know that circle $S^1$ isn't homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$ and that they have same cardinality, but I am not sure about surjection.

Thanks!

Comment: Think of the closure in the plane of the graph on $\sin(1/x)$ for $0<x<1 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on the topologist's sine curve gives an especially tantalizing example. Take the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ for $0<x<1$, the line segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$, and finally draw a curve from $(1, \sin(1))$ around the graph into the negative-$x$-half plane, and join it back up with the line segment. Something like the drawing below (different part in different colors):

[image]

You cannot surject a circle onto that, but it still clearly divides the plane into an outside and an inside like a circle would.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Every continuous image of $[0,1]$ is locally-connected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the union of the line segments joining $[0,0]$ to $[1,1/n]$ for positive integers $n$ and to $[1,0]$.